# What does it mean to divide groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_set#Known_difference_sets) a group is defined as division (?) of groups:
$$G=GF(q^{n+2})^*/GF(q)^*,$$
where $GF(q)^*$ is the multiplicative group of Galois field's GF(q) non-zero elements.

What would the $G$ contain?

Suppose I had these groups:
$$GF(3)^* = \{1,2\}$$
$$GF(3^2)^* = \{1,2,\alpha ,2\alpha,1+\alpha,2+\alpha,1+2\alpha,2+2\alpha\}$$

What would $G = GF(3^2)^*/GF(3)^*$ contain?

Comment: It is called a quotient group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, $ GF(3^2)^*/GF(3)^* = \{ \{1,2\}, \{\alpha,2\alpha\}, \{1+\alpha,2+2\alpha\}, \{1+2\alpha,2+\alpha\} \}$ where $\{a,b\} \cdot \{ c,d \} = \{ ac, ad, bc, bd\}$ and coincidentally (“normal subgroup”) that last set always only has 2 elements.

It is easier to see here if you replace 2 with -1, then you get $ GF(3^2)^*/GF(3)^* = \{ \{\pm1\}, \{\pm\alpha\}, \{\pm(1+\alpha)\}, \{\pm(1+2\alpha)\} \}$  and $\{\pm a \} \cdot \{\pm c\} = \{ \pm ac \}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can not in general divide two groups. However, you can do this if one is a normal subgroup of another see [Quotient group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group)

In your case $GF^{*}(q) \subset GF(q^{n+2})^*$ in a natural way, and I believe that is what is meant in the article.